# IPTables allow NTP Time Server

Tags: rhel, iptables, ntp, ntpd

I am new to IPTables.  I have an existing config that seems to work well.  I am not sure I know how to add NTP to the rule `Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` correctly.  My goal is to add an additional rule to allow NTP to enter the server so it can act as a NTP server for my network.  Would I simply need `iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT` and then of course if it works `iptables save`  I'm not confident whether I should be using -I Insert or -A Append, or if it is much more difficult.  Below is my existing config shown with `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:squid
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: The first line of RH-Firewall-1-INPUT is allowing all traffic of any protocol to come in.  With that said, you shouldn't have to modify your ruleset to get NTP working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your last rule is an unconditional `REJECT` I would do it with a `-I` since appending it would create a rule that would never be reached. `ntpd` only communicates over udp/123 so allowing that traffic and RELATED,ESTABLISHED is often good enough on its own.